# How to check Null value for Date Object

Tags: java, date, jsf-2, richfaces, nullpointerexception

I am using JSF 2.0 and RichFaces 3.3. In my View user will pich a date from a calendar. Tag used is `<rich:calendar>`. This is mapped in backing bean with `Date` object. However this field is optional and hence when user does not select a date the backing bean getter for this particular entry returns `null`, which is right.

My problem is that I have to store this date in DB. So before storing I am type casting it in this manner:

```
if (newProfile.get(Constants.DETAILS_EXPIRY_DATE_1).equals(null)) {
    this.cStmt.setDate(15,null);
} else {
    java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(((java.util.Date)newProfile.get(Constants.DETAILS_EXPIRY_DATE_1)).getTime());
    this.cStmt.setDate(15,sqlDate);
}
```

However it is throwing a `NullPointerException` in the `if` condition. I want to insert `null` value in DB when user does not select a date. How can I do this?

Comment: Post the stack trace. By the look of it if you are getting nullpoint at if it can only be from 'newProfile' meaning it is not initialized nothing to do with do.

Comment: @Shahzeb, it might also be that the `newProfile.get(Constants.DETAILS_EXPIRY_DATE_1)` returns a `null`.

Comment: true @The. Ankit post stacktrace also show some more code .

Comment: Yeah...that line is returning null but that is why I want to check for null value....I know when won't select a date it will have null value..and since it contains null value I will store null value without type casting..But if condition itself is throwing Null Pointer Exception,.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to be more *robust* in avoiding NullPointerException,

```
if (newProfile != null) {
    Object obj = newProfile.get(Constants.DETAILS_EXPIRY_DATE_1);
    if (obj == null) {
        this.cStmt.setDate(15, null);
    } else {
        java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(((java.util.Date)obj).getTime());
                this.cStmt.setDate(15,sqlDate);

    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Try `if(newProfile.get(Constants.DETAILS_EXPIRY_DATE_1) == null)`

For String, you can use equals() method. Also, objects need null check before using equals method to avoid NullPointerException.

Comment: Not only this answer is incorrect but has also got an upvote -unreal.

Comment: @Vanathi My problem seems to be solved...I assumed that along with String, Date object can also be checked as null using .equals method and that is why it failed intially...

Comment: @Vanathi, your answer is correct but your explanation is wrong.

Comment: It worked for me. plz some expert may explain why is this wrong?